# Allowing a person object to be created under a locality

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am using Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services. I notice when I right click on a locality entry, L=dublin, and select New Object there is no option to create a person object.

[image: Create Object Dialog]

I am very new to LDAP and AD LDS. How would I go about updating AD LDS so I could create a person object beneath a locality object?